# LowpassFilter and LeastSquaresFilterKernel implementation

Tags: implementation-details, signal-processing, reference-request

I'm in the troublesome phase to port *Mathematica* code into another programming language. I cannot find a proper reference on the algorithm used in the [`LeastSquaresFilterKernel`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LeastSquaresFilterKernel.html) function of *Mathematica*. This last function is used by `LowpassFilter` as shown in the examples, despite the fact that I have tried with my signal and it does not work in the same way.

Can anyone help me in finding the detailed implementation of `LowpassFilter` or some reference for `LeastSquaresFilterKernel`?

Comment: Have you tried asking Wolfram Support? Unless it is in the documentation, they would be the most reliable source for this kind of information.

Comment: No, but I will try for sure. How do you contact them?

Comment: You can use [this form](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/).

Comment: If they respond, you can then answer your question yourself.